# Downloading an mp3 from link inside app

Tags: macos, cocoa, download, mp3, hyperlink

i'm making an mac app that downloads an mp3 from a link.
For example, this link: http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/VGGUdzU69Ng5?stream_token=2U9W2 
As you can see, it is an mp3 file.
How can i download it to a specific path?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `NSURLDownload`:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/VGGUdzU69Ng5?stream_token=2U9W2"];
NSString* destinationPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someFile.mp3"];

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLDownload* download = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
[download setDestination:destinationPath allowOverwrite:NO];
```

Ideally you'd set an object as the delegate so you can receive progress notifications and then release the `NSURLDownload` object when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to [set a policy delegate for your web view](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setPolicyDelegate%3a), and have that delegate [respond to the question of what to do with that link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adecidePolicyForNavigationAction%3arequest%3aframe%3adecisionListener%3a) by [telling the listener to download](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDecisionListener_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WebPolicyDecisionListener/download).

Edit: Oh, missed the part about “to a specific path”. I've no idea on that; sorry. I hope someone else can fill in that aspect.